# Работа с CSV файлом в Java

Tags: java, excel, csv

Всем доброго времени суток!

Прошу уточнить как с помощью стандартных библиотек Java работать с CSV фалом ( если можно перечислите необходимые  Import, которые следует использовать)?

1. Задача в том, чтобы посчитать кол-во встречающихся значений по отдельности из колонки Names. Например sbt-lupov-av встречается всего 2 раза. Я просто не понимаю как обращаться к конкретным ячейкам в файле ( раньше работал с XLS файлами с помощью библиотеки JXL, там за это отвечает метод `getCell(int x, int b // координаты ячеек)` .
2. И самое главное как привязать значение из колонки `AccountedTime`  к каждому человеку и приплюсовать их? Ну например тот же самый `sbt-lupov-av` встречается  с значением  `6` и `3` , т.е. сумма его (которая мне в итоге и нужна) равняется `9`.

[image: Вот этот файл CSV]

Comment: в стандартной библиотеки нет такой функциональности. вы можете просто читать файл и разбирать его самостоятельно.

Comment: csv файл - это просто текстовый файл с разделителями. Вы можете просто открывать его как обычный текстовый и работать с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку Apache Commons CSV. Она поддерживает формат CSV-файлов созданных через Excel. Там же есть возможность обращаться к колонкам по имени (считается, что имена задаются первой строкой в файле; как раз Ваш случай). Документация по вариантам использования - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

> И самое главное как привязать значение из колонки AccountedTime к каждому человеку и приплюсовать их? Ну например тот же самый sbt-lupov-av встречается с значением 6 и 3 , т.е. сумма его (которая мне в итоге и нужна) равняется 9

Используйте для этого HashMap, где в качестве ключа будет имя, а в качестве значения текущая сумма. Перебирая все записи, следуйте такому алгоритму:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("file.csv");
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String name = record.get("Names");
    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(record.get("AccountedTime"));
    map.put(name, map.containsKey(name) ? map.get(name) + value, value);
}
```